# Prove that any number greater that one can be uniquely written in arbitrary base.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $n$ and $a$ are positive integers greater than one. Prove that $n$ can be uniquely written in the form:
$$n=c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+...+c_ma^m$$
where $c_i$s are integers, $0\leq c_i\leq a-1$ and $0\leq i\leq m$ (use induction on $n$).

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? (Also, the problem statement is missing some condition on $a$)

Comment: Seems like homework. What have you tried? As a hint, it might help to first do a special case such as $a = 2$. Once you understand that, try $a = 3$. If you can do those 2 bases, you should be able to generalize to arbitrary bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove this for any $a \geq 2$ and $n \geq 0$; we need to include $0$ and $1$ for the induction to work.

First, as base cases consider the integers less than $a$. Expressing $n$ in the desired form forces all of the $c_i$ for $i \geq 1$ to be $0$, since otherwise the expression grows too large. Then there is a unique integer $0 \leq c_0=n < a$ which makes the expression valid, as required.

Now with these cases covered, take as induction hypothesis that the claim is true for all $n<a^k$.

Let $a^k\leq n < a^{k+1}$. Then there is a unique integer $c_k$ such that $c_k a^k \leq n < (c_k +1)a^k$, and we must have $1\leq c_k <a$ since otherwise we have $n<a^k$ or $n \geq a^{k+1}$, which contradicts our assumption on $n$. Further, $0 \leq n - c_k a^k < a^k$, so this value is by hypothesis expressible uniquely as a sum of the given form:
$$n-c_k a^k = c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+...+c_{k-1}a^{k-1}.$$
Therefore we obtain the unique expression
$$n = c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+...+c_{k-1}a^{k-1}+c_k a^k,$$
which completes the induction.